# Completely non-GUI (or terminal) way to connect to 802.1x wired network

Tags: terminal, network-interface, deepin, 802.1x

How can I connect to a 802.1x PEAP secured wired network without using any GUI on Debian? I want a non-GUI way as I am using a customized GUI. Also the network doesn't take any certificate for PEAP. How can I connect to such a network?

Comment: Have you tried wicd? It's a command line tool, and there's a Debian package, but I don't know if it can do PEAP.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nmtui`, if you are using network-manager. Nmtui is a terminal ui for the networkmanager. It lets you edit, (de-)activate and monitor available connections.